# SQL Server 2008 - how to export/backup the last 3 months of data from the database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, export

I need to troubleshoot the production SQL Server 2008 database, so I want to export/backup only the last 3 month of data contained in it in order to import it into the test SQL box and try to troubleshoot the issue there. Production and test SQL Servers are in two different forests/domains. Would you be so kind to advise me what is the better way of doing that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**What you ask is not possible**

Unless you have timestamps in each individual table, identifying "the last 3 months of data" is impossible.

Even if you do have timestamps, just trying to pull all rows from all tables where the timestamp is within the last 3 months could lead to an inconsistent state.  For example, you could have a Customer table and an Orders table.  A given customer might be 5 months old, but there might be an order for that customer that is 1 day old.  Pulling the 1 day order but not pulling the 5 month old customer it references would lead to an order without a customer.

In short, I don't see how you can do this from the live database in the general case.  If you have a fairly simple schema, please share it.  Perhaps there is a solution for your specific case.

**An Alternative**

If slicing the data is not possible, and your concern is the amount of data, consider slicing the data a different way.  Perhaps pull the data for 10% of your customers or something along those lines.  If you share your schema (assuming it's not too complex) I can make a more concrete recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with timestamps, write your own migration code where traverse each table and get the data from last 3 months and dump into your new database.